# Corrupt or broken CR2 file?

Tags: raw

My photographer friend sent me some .cr2 files to look at in adobe bridge/photoshop cs6.

I can open a few of them, but some I can't open in photoshop nor bridge.

If I try to open it in photoshop I get"Photoshop cannot open this file, make sure you have the latest camera raw version blabla". Which I have, I updated the camera raw version. I can't view these files in bridge either.

The weird thing is that I CAN see some of the thumbnails of these files in windows explorer.

Anyone an idea what is going on?

I tried converters and all that but they don't work.

Comment: The thumbnails are from embedded JPG's, so they might not be affected if the file is corrupt (or can't be read for another reason).  Have you looked through the related questions?  Do any of those resemble your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair a corrupt .nef file?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27103/how-can-i-repair-a-corrupt-nef-file)

Comment: What camera are they from? This is kind of important. And, what version of ACR did you update to?

Comment: They're from a Canon 600D. ACR version 7.1.0.354

Answer (score 1):

There is a preview thumbnail embedded in the start of the file.  It is possible the storage of the RAW data became corrupt however the thumbnail preview remained intact.  Software that only looks at the thumbnail would be able to display it, but the RAW file itself may be ruined.

I'd recommend trying the software that came with the camera to verify it isn't simply a compatibility problem, but I also wouldn't hold my breath since it's fairly unlikely that the latest version of Adobe Camera Raw wouldn't be able to open it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response. I'll consider them lost then.

Comment: @Robert To expand on this answer a little, try to use a file extracting program to see if there is a larger JPG you can retrieve.  I have had corrupt files and have used a program called "FileJuicer" (free trial) to extract both the thumbnail JPG AJ is referring to, as well as a much larger (> 1000px) JPG version. It's not perfect and sometimes doesn't work, but it is worth a shot if the images are important enough.

Comment: I tried with a pc tool called BitmapRip, unfortunately it doesn't work. I might try later with another tool.

Comment: I tried this tool: http://www.gdzid.com/QJFC.htm

Worked for the files I could already open, extracts a jpeg of just a plain color plane from some of the broken files and doesn't recognize a jpeg in most files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest the blatantly obvious route that you've probably already tried (but it's always worth a shot).  Talk to your photographer friend and ask him if he still has copies that are readable.  If so, ask him to send another copy...

Comment: Best solution, but unfortunately he "cut" them from his camera to his desktop. So the corrupt ones are the only ones he has.

Comment: And I suppose this happened a while ago - so undeleting them from the card is also not an option? (assuming the card has been re-used)

Comment: The card has been re-used. Yes :(