# Why are my RAW format photos pink?

Tags: raw, data-corruption

I just recovered some deleted photos, and noticed they are all pink. Is there any way for me to fix all my photos?[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes this sort of RAW file corruption?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14385/what-causes-this-sort-of-raw-file-corruption)  It isn't exactly the same, but it is the same general kind of thing with the same recovery concerns and chances of success.

Comment: I'd like to leave this question open because I think the particular symptom (magenta; see my answer) is interesting. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Before doing anything irreversible I would suggest to check the RAW file with another program; if they use different 'raw driver' it might be some unexpected incompatibility another program might be able to compensate. Grasping for straws, admittedly.

Answer (score 5):

That's not pink — that's magenta. The difference is significant because magenta is the mix of blue and red primaries, with no green. That implies that the green channel information for that part of the file is damaged. But also, it's pretty clear that most of the image is messed up far beyond beyond that. I'd write this one off as not salvageable.

If you still have the memory card, you might try different recovery software. If that doesn't work, I suppose your best bet is to take another photo.

Comment: Fuchsia if you will

Comment: whats the difference between pink magenta and fuchsia?

Comment: Pink is technically a pale red; in RGB the red value is high and green and blue slightly less so (and blue and green are in roughly equal proportion). In practice, pink refers to a wide variety of similar hues. Magenta is specifically a primary color in CMYK, and the secondary color in RGB between red and blue. Interestingly, it does not appear in the spectrum of light — our vision system just interprets the absence of green in this way. Fuchsia is synonymous with magenta in web design, but is sometimes more red in other contexts.