# Image being corrupted in DSLR

Tags: dslr, digital, image-quality, storage, data-corruption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do my images get distorted on my Nikon DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6045/why-do-my-images-get-distorted-on-my-nikon-dslr)

I have been shooting with my D90 for quite sometime and I have just encountered the following problem. What could have cause this ?? I tried reformatting the SD Card but we still encounter this problem. How can I recover my corrupted image and prevent this from happening again??

**Edited** It is corrupted visible on the camera's LCD screen

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG5VF.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq4cq.jpg]

Comment: Have you tried using a different memory card?

Comment: it is corrupted visible on the camera's LCD screen

Answer (score 1):

mattdm's link looks to have the same problem as you.  Please have a look at that question.

To figure out where things are going wrong, you want to eliminate things one at a time:

- try a different card.  If that works, you know it's your card
- if you have reformatted the card from Windows, try again from the camera menu
- try shooting RAW + JPG and see if both files look the same.  If the camera is faulty, you might get lucky and find it can't product JPGs reliably, but the RAW file is fine.  If so you'll just have to switch to shooting RAW and converting to JPG out of camera.

Comment: But it is corrupted visible on the camera's LCD screen