# Nikon D3100 corrupt files?

Tags: nikon, raw, nikon-d3100

I am new to using the D3100, and was out with my family at the weekend taking pictures. When I got home I noticed that a few images had not been saved correctly. Does anyone know any reason why this could be so i can avoid it in the future please?

I was storing the images in the .nef format (RAW, I do believe) and am using a 32GB Transcend SD Card - class 10.

Comment: This is probably a good starting point: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/6048/5551

Comment: Just for confirmation, yes, .nef is Nikons RAW format.

Comment: Hi there. You mention that the images had "not saved correctly", how did you realise this? Were they just not on the card or did they appear to be there and you could not open them? Have you tried another card? Do bare in mind that you will need an application that is able to read .NEF files such as Adobe Camera Raw/Nikon Capture etc. If you are unable to view NEF's in Windows you can download the NEF codec that will allow you to view .NEF's in Windows Picture Viewer. [link]http://www.nikonimglib.com/nefcodec/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you insert your card into the camera, you should format it in the camera. Many times, errors occur when you remove the card from the camera and insert it onto a PC, which could write junk onto the card that the camera cannot understand. Each time you pull the card from the camera and replace it, you compound the chance that corruption will occur. Nikon provides a menu command ( and dedicated buttons on some bodies ) that will format the card in the camera, which will minimize the number of memory card related issues you'll encounter. I know this doesn't help your current problem, but could minimize future problems. I originally found this solution on Ken Rockwell's site in his D90 user's guide, but the tip is also found here [Rockwell Pro Tip about Formatting Memory Cards](http://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/cf-sd.htm#format)

I have witnessed this corruption several time personally, and have not seen it since I've started with the format card on every insertion policy.

I also wouldn't assume the card is bad until I tried the formatting. A class 10, 32gb card cannot be that old, and is not cheap. I still use 4gb trancend cards that are probably 3 years old and see heavy use without issue.

Comment: I cannot agree with this answer at all. Every time you reformat your are adding write cycles to the card. All you are doing in effect is overwriting a small area that is the file allocation table. The firmware in the card may write this to new physical memory areas each time, dependant on the firmware, but overall you are, however slightly, *increasing* the chance of a write error. If a card ever starts to play up, bin it. They are not worth the effort if they ever start to fail. I get through hundreds, if not thousands a year for work [video, not photography] & that's our policy.

Comment: contd.. the fails you see are far more likely due to a bad unmount from the computer, which necessitates a reformat. That doesn't make the reformat itself a good idea - it just means your unmount routine needs to be more strict.

Answer (score 0):

Are they OK in camera or not? If OK in camera but not elsewhere look to a transfer problem, otherwise look to a card or camera problem, start by checking all connectors are clean. Had you formatted the card in camera before first use?

Comment: No, on the preview screen they were just little red squares with a red cross inside. So could not view them. The camera is working fine, out of around 200 images only 10 did not save/were corrupted.

I formatted the SD card before use. I did use it in my DRIFT HD action camera, and that did not save a few videos previously. So i am starting to think its an issue with the SD Card! My smaller 16GB SD has not had these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your SD card is corrupt. Try another card? I wouldn't use that card if I were you.