# What causes double appearance in a single picture?

Tags: multiple-exposure

My kids was taking photos of me and my wife and in one of them I appeared double on each side of my wife. Would you help me understand how it happened. We used a LG phone. Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeAHT.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am quite sure that the answer is here: [Is it possible to get a double exposure with a digital camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30464/is-it-possible-to-get-a-double-exposure-with-a-digital-camera/30465#30465)

Your wife's camera phone has a feature called "HDR", where it takes two pictures in quick succession and combines them, in order to better capture both bright and dark areas. It happens quickly, but if the subject (here, it's you) moves quickly, you'll get this kind of doubled image. This also explains the blurred representation of your wife.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt but I have one more question if you would allow. Is this double image possible to happen with two pictures not in quick succession? I am asking because it took time to pass behind my wife's back, switch the car keys from my right hand to the left, put my right arm around my wife's neck and finally pause for the picture. what do you think about photo stitching?  Thank you so much for taking the time and effort to answer. I really appreciate!!!

Comment: I guess it's possible that the camera has a special mode that does that. Were you using the default app? Or, it could be that it took longer than expected due to some software glitch.