# Double exposure with Canon 700D?

Tags: canon, exposure, camera-settings

How can I take double exposure wth my Canon 700D? I am unable to do this.

Comment: Why do you think this body should be able to do it ?

Comment: Why don't you take two shots and merge them in postprocessing?

Answer (score 3):

From Canon itself, **it is not possible**.

However, you can still use *old-school* flash techniques to do it (basically, long exposure and multiple flash), see [Is it possible to get a double exposure with a digital camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30464/is-it-possible-to-get-a-double-exposure-with-a-digital-camera)

Sources :

- last update 19/09/2014 (700D listed): http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/8201440300.html
- last update 11/04/2015 (700D listed): https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART138059

Dates are in format dd/mm/yy.