# Images colors getting distorted

Tags: data-corruption

When I click on a pictures to view them they seem to look perfectly fine on my laptop, like this:

[image]

But when I open them in the picture viewer or any other editor the colors are getting distorted:

[image]

Is there a way I can recover the images
I am pretty sure the problem was the card reader, but I have already deleted the images from CF card and I need to fix the already copied raw images. The image uploaded is JPEG. I have the same images in RAW format which are getting completely distorted because of the colors

My camera is a Canon 7D.

Comment: Also see [Why are my RAW images corrupt but the previews okay?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61600/why-are-my-raw-images-corrupt-but-the-previews-okay)

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I wouldn't describe this as "colors getting distorted" — from that, I expected a mild to moderate color shift, as from a problem with color spaces. Here, the image is _all messed up_, and the only reason color comes into it is that photographs are essentially _made_ of color.

Comment: *And*, also note that the jpeg preview (your first image) _also_ shows data corruption, although it happens to be to a lesser degree. (See that weird line?)

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that you have a bad data card. It's also possible that a bad card reader or interruption in the copy process introduced the corruption. You can try copying again with a different connection, or to altogether a different device.

Because the image looks corrupted both before and after you copy it to your computer, the card is the most likely suspect.

Try the process with a different card. Test a new card with something easy to photograph. It's possible that any part of the process, camera, card, reader, cable, computer, is introducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first image is a corrupt image file.  The colours *are* distorted, just not as severely.  You can also see that where the colours change the image is shifted.  This is caused by some missing or wrong data in the file.

Similar corruptions in the `CR2` file have also occurred, just at a different point, which is why it looks more severe.

Since you have deleted them, unless you can recover them from the CF card using [recovery software](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/how-can-i-recover-photo-files-from-a-memory-card-with-a-corrupt-filesystem) then the affected images are as good as gone.

Answer (score -1):

Note sure what your image is showing ?  Is it a composite or screenshot or what ?

I would point out that screens ( any screens ) will have different colour profiles and unless your OS and software are colour managed and calibrated correctly no two displays will look quite the same.

[Cambridge In Colour - Colour Management Basics](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/color-management1.htm)

Comment: @anusha you suggested an edit on my post with another image of your own.  It would be more helpful to other users to post that image by editing you own post.  The norm would be to add a section with a headline "Update" so people can notice it.  I will skip your suggested edit to my post pending your decision on that.  The problem your second image shows is either a corrupt file ( time to ditch the memory card ) or your system does not have up to date raw codecs installed - check your OS vendor and your camera vendor for a possible newer version of codecs.

Comment: Actually, the SE preference is *not* to include "edit", "update" or the like when making an edit.

Comment: Yeah, there's a history for people who are curious, and a year — or for that matter, a week! — from now, no one cares about the order. Rather than a recorded dialog, we strive for straightforward, understandable questions and direct answers.

Comment: Anyway, based on the (attempted) edit, this clearly isn't the answer. I recommend deletion.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply. It is a problem with the card reader. During copy the image go corrupted. But I have already deleted the image on the CF card.