# Why is Lightroom showing a corrupted image?

Tags: data-corruption, lightroom-5

In Lightroom 5.7.1 (OSX 10.10), Lightroom is showing a weird, corrupted version of many JPG (not raw) files in my library:

[image]

Opening or previewing the image directly (Quicklook or any other app) shows that the image is just fine:

[image]

This is happening only to some folders (but many of them), and is progressive - as I open an old folder, it will re-render the original previews and change from the original, good preview, to the corrupted version.

Selecting 'develop' still shows the corrupted image, too.

Discarding the 1:1 previews has no effect.

Comment: Related:[Why are my RAW images corrupt but the previews okay?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/61600/15871)

Comment: Is that in LR a raw? Because the second screen shot is a jpeg, ie. a different file?

Comment: The original is a JPG file, not raw!

Comment: As you can see, the color layer is correct, but the luminance layer is incorrect for the width part, and correct for the height part. This is usually a wrong implementation of the file reader, or at least a wrong information about the *stride* used to read the data, which is in your case half of the correct value. I would recommend to reinstall Lightroom. Which other imaging software do you have ? They might share libraries (dylib files), and one of them updated those but compatibility has been broken.

Comment: Beside the stride problem, can you try to purge the cache to update from the original, even though it's JPG images ? Edit / Preferences / Performance / Purge cache (there are 2 of them).

Comment: @Soleil - no 'purge cache' except for a RAW cache in my Lightroom (5.7.1). The shared library issue makes sense and will try reinstalling!

Comment: @Simbamangu and for those who reproduce this problem on Windows, there is [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) that allows us to track which are the shared libraries that are needed, and [process explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) that allows us to do that dynamically with the processes.


You can do some tests on OSX and Windows virtual machines, so you have a virgin environment, you'll be sure you're using the libraries coming from lightroom.

Comment: On mac/bsd, try [an alternative to process explorer](https://alternativeto.net/software/process-explorer/?platform=mac) to find out which shared libraries are being used.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be corrupted raw files.

Generally the normal software will show you the embedded JPEG in the raw (a small file), Lightroom, Photoshop, DXO, Capture One and others read the RAW.

I'm quite sure you transfer yours raws directly from your camera.

Try to transfer your files from your camera with a (different) card reader. Check if you don't have any memory problem. A good way to check transfer is to compare checksum files from the source to the target.

Perhaps your card is corrupted or damaged or it is a "fake" one, format it **in your camera** with low level formating  procedure.

Comment: I've edited my original post to confirm that it's happening to JPG files, not raw. These are files that have been happily and correctly in my Lightroom catalog for a long time, and are now getting updated to appear in both the viewer and develop tabs as those corrupted images. *The original* image on disk is just fine if viewed in Graphicconverter or Preview!