# Raw photo problem

Tags: raw

[image]

I was taking photos last night at a formal function and two of my photos came out like this one in the attachment? Can anyone tell me what would cause this to happen? Thanx

Comment: @mattdm Not sure that quite answers this question which is "what caused this to happen" rather than "what can I do about it now".

Comment: Well, see also [Why are my RAW images corrupt but the previews okay?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61600/why-are-my-raw-images-corrupt-but-the-previews-okay), which was closed as a duplicate of [Why do images get “corrupted”?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6045/why-do-images-get-corrupted), which is about JPEG files but basically _does_ apply to the fundamentals.

Comment: Even a single bit error can cause something like this.  My raw file discussed in https://superuser.com/q/794874/12296 had a similar corruption.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to partially corrupted memory cards.