# Is it banding problem with the camera or with the SD card?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting

[image]

Hello, I just came back from a day of shooting with my Canon and several images are banded like this. Some have horizontal banding. I was shooting fast. Is it a write to disk problem, did the SSD card just go bad, or is it the camera? Thanks! --Joy

Comment: This question is hard to answer without a little more information. Can you please edit the question to include answers to these questions: what model canon camera?, what brand/size SD card?, were you shooting in RAW or jpeg, if jpeg, what settings?. Answers to these will help us help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do images get "corrupted"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6045/why-do-images-get-corrupted)

Comment: For an in-depth analysis of those that might be interested it would be necessary to have the unedited jpeg file available. Are you able to reproduce the problem with shooting fast again? Try shooting something that moves fast to see if each band is just a corrupted version of a whole same image, or if each band is part of a buffer residue of a previous frame.

Answer (score 2):

A banded image like this is caused by the file being corrupted. This can be caused by a couple of things:

- **Incomplete copying** - did you safely eject the SD card when you removed it from your computer? Can you try copying the file from the card again.
- **Corruption on disk** - there could be issues with the hard drive on your computer, and the files have become corrupted there, this is unlikely unless you have seen other issues with your computer.
- **Incomplete writing onto the memory card** - if you eject the card too quickly from the camera after taking the shot, then it's possible that the camera didn't have time to finish writing to the card. This is unlikely if affected images are interspersed with OK ones.
- **Failing Memory card** - probably the most likely issue, check the camera with a different card. If the card is failing, then just replace it.
- **Corruption in camera processing/sensor** - unlikely but if you've ruled out everything above then there may just be an issue with the data pathways in the camera itself. If so, the camera is probably dead.

Comment: Data loss from a poor connection between camera or memory card reader and the computer.

Comment: @MichaelClark - a poor connection/cable could result in failed/slow transfers, but  CRC checksums are used during data transfer across USB, so data corruption from a dodgy cable/connection isn't possible.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the OS using the correct drivers...

Comment: @MichaelClark reliable data transfer would be practically impossible without verifying the checksums, so if a driver is capable of receiving data, its very unlikely to be ignoring the checksum