# Transferred files from Canon camera, now files are corrupted (?)

Tags: canon, error, data-corruption

I recently transferred some photos from the sd card inside my canon camera (by cutting and pasting into a usb file) and for some reason, some files have been cut (like some blocks of the image are coloured.. like this:

[image]

The above is a thumbnail. But sometimes the files' thumbnails look fine but when I view them (with Photo Viewer from windows 10) they appear like that too (like blocks of it gone). Some of them, I try to open but I can't open them at all! I'd really like to know how to fix this... It's kind of upsetting since these photos are my graduation photos...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do images get "corrupted"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6045/why-do-images-get-corrupted)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the file transfer process from the card to the computer was not error-free. The problem may be with the card, the card reader, contacts...

If you still have the pictures on the card, check if they can be viewed OK in the camera. If yes, then try to transfer them by connecting the camera with its dedicated USB cable instead of taking out the card. This method worked for me with an old XD-Picture card which was producing corrupted files in a card reader but still worked OK in-camera.

In any case You should also try another card reader and consider buying a new SD-card.

[edit] Or if the faulty file transfer was through cable with the card in the camera, then try the opposite by taking out the card and using a card reader - and check the USB cable and contacts. You can try to clean any contacts with pure isopropyl alcohol.